# Java compiler automatically renaming parameters (obfuscating)

Tags: java, compiler-construction, obfuscation, javac

When I compile the code I am writing, then look at in a a JD Gui, methods show up with headers such as the following:

```
public void growSurface(Random paramRandom, int paramInt1, int paramInt2){
```

I am compiling through a .bat file.  Is there a way to specify that I don't want to obfuscate the code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default `javac` is not including debug information in generated `class` files. This information is e.g. method parameter names (but method and field names are always stored to allow reflection). When the parameter names are not known, JD-GUI and other decompilers are making up some reasonable names. They are not obfuscated - simply they aren't there.

Compile your code with `-g` flag:

```
javac -g SomeClass.java
```

Just checked JD-GUI - it shows correct parameter names then.