# Spring Cacheable how to pass method invocation result to key?

Tags: spring, spring-el

Consider following snippet, I am trying to call a method of propertiesContainer which would be used as a key.

```
@Cacheable(value = EhCacheManagerApi.CACHE_X_TOKEN, key = ("#{propertiesContainer.getId()}"))
public String getToken(PropertiesContainer propertiesContainer)
```

I cannot seem to figure out the correct spel expression for key, current format gives me:

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1043E:(pos 1): Unexpected token. Expected 'identifier' but was 'lcurly({)'
```

Before I tried  `key = ("#propertiesContainer.id")` and `key = ("#propertiesContainer.getId()")`

propertiesContainer is an interface which has method `getId` returning `String`.

So presumably this is not the same as bean method invocation with SpEL?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the pure expression without the parenthesis:

```
@Cacheable(value = EhCacheManagerApi.CACHE_X_TOKEN, key="propertiesContainer.id")
```

This works for me in Spring 4.3.3 where PropertiesContainer is an interface with a getId() method.

Also, you might need to use `#p0.id` instead of the method parameter name if you don't have debug info in your compiled code. See [the accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889428/spring-cacheable-with-complex-keys-still-executed) but that would give you a different error I suspect.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this

```
    @Cacheable(value = EhCacheManagerApi.CACHE_X_TOKEN, key = "#{T(java.lang.String).format('%d-%d', #propertiesContainer.id)}")
```